# Sum of Product of Absolutely Convergent Series gives Absolutely Convergent Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have come across the following problem and I believe I have a correct solution, but I had a question about the necessity of the hypotheses:

> Prove that if $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n$ are absolutely convergent series, then $\sum_{n, m = 1}^{\infty} a_n b_m$ is absolutely convergent and converges to
> \[
> \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n \right) \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n \right).
> \]

I was able to prove this by simply writing the sum of the products as a double nested sum and factoring out the inner sum, however the only part of my proof that depends on the series being absolutely convergent is to show that $\sum_{n, m = 1}^{\infty} a_n b_m$ is absolutely convergent. Is correct?

Namely, is it true that for *any convergent series* the sum of their products converges to the product of their sums, or did I make a mistake somewhere in my proof?

Comment: If a series $\sum_n a_n$ is not absolutely convergent, then it is conditionally convergent, which, as you may know, means that rearranging the terms can affect the limit. Note that we can describe this since there is a canonical order in which we sum the series $a_1, a_1 + a_2,...$ and so on. With a double sum, there is no such canonical order, so if the series on the LHS were conditionally convergent, the question would get a lot more confusing. I think that this is the main reason for specifying the series on the LHS are absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without absolute convergence, what you mean by the notation

$$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty a_n b_m$$

is ill-defined. For absolute convergence, we can say: define some bijection between

$$\{(n,m):n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$$

by $s_k$ with the notation

$$s_k(1)=x\text{ in }(x,y)$$

$$s_k(2)=y\text{ in }(x,y)$$

Then

$$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty a_n b_m=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{s_k(1)} b_{s_k(2)}=L$$

for a specific $L$ regardless of which bijection is used above. If one of the sums is conditionally convergent (or both) then you can rearrange the terms to get any limit you want, including $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Thus, for a conditionally convergent series there exists a bijection

$$\{(n,m):n,m\in\mathbb{N}\}\leftrightarrow \mathbb{N}$$

(called $s_k$) such that

$$\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty a_n b_m=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{s_k(1)} b_{s_k(2)}=L$$

where $L$ is any real number of positive/negative infinity.